# Animate colour change, in text with the beat

Tags: animation-nodes

how do i change the text colour like this guys intro?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdCiMz1iOFE

--Edit--
here is the screenshot, like how do i animate the colour change of the text

[image]

Comment: Use the Please use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135813/edit) link at the bottom of your question (i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and [add a screenshot](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1081/23985) instead of the link to a video. It's easier and less time consuming for us to answer the question without having to watch videos to figure out what people want.

Comment: Pull the mouse cursor above the color and hit I to insert a keyframe for the color to the actual frame.